# How to keep textareas from overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have two textareas

```
<textarea>Text area 1</textarea>
<textarea>Text area 2</textarea>
```

I want to position themselves ontop of eachother like so:

[image]

However i do not want to use `<br>`.

Is there another way to do this in CSS?  For example, messing with `textarea` `margin` or `display` properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't use you want to use `<br>`?

Comment: Throw em in a div and do a position:absolute

Comment: For simplicity, I want to keep as much as I can in CSS.  Additionally, I want to have more control over how many pixels they are spaced apart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just make the textareas block elements.

```
textarea {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    clear:both;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5C8MC/1/)

Comment: display:block isn't moving them.  I should mention they are inside of a div.

Comment: It wouldn't matter that they are in a div. `display:block;` tells the element to take up 100% of the width of the line it is on. You can try adding `clear:both;` as well. Updated answer.

Comment: I had position:absolute on textareas.  Upon removing it, they automatically moving into line.

Comment: Good to hear, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

just set the textarea's to `display: block` and then you can use `margin` to adjust the spacing

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q22At/)